# redirect always on HTTP

Tags: angular, url-rewriting

I would like to redirect url for my Angular 5 app to `HTTPS` rather than `HTTP` when I'm trying in browser like,

`host-name/Site1/`

it should automatically become,

`https://host-name/Site1/`

I tried below url re-write rule in `wen.config`, but it's always going to `http`, please suggest reason. Thanks!

`<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to http" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*" negate="false" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Found" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>`

Comment: How is web.config going to affect the requests sent by the browser? Do you want your angular app to only send XHRs to `https`? Because this can't be configured server side.

Comment: Add . in url attribute. <match url=".*" negate="false" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use an interceptor for that.

```js
export class HttpsInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (!req.url.startsWith('https://')) {
      const clone = req.clone();
      // Append your HTTPS here
      return next
        .handle(clone);
    }
    return next
      .handle(req);
  }
}
```